Add HTML Table Rows to mailto message
This is driving my nuts - I have a ASPX form page with bunch of checkboxes and dropdowns and a table. I add rows to the table using text boxes with parts details and qty. Once everything is completed, the user hits Send Mail button which fires a mailto event. I can get everything into the body except the table rows. This is what I tried now, but now I get this error for line 99:
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:
Line 99:         string itemNumber = ((Label)row.FindControl("ItemNr")).Text;
My code behind looks like this:
        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlStaffList.SelectedValue))
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select Requester');</script>");
        return;
    }

    string email = "test@group.com";
    string subject = "Internal Procurement Request";
    string body = 
        "Requester: " + ddlStaffList.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +
        "Requested Date: " + txtDateFrom.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "%0D%0A" +
        "Additional QR Inspection Required: " + rbtnQA.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +   
        "Product Control Status: " + rbtnProductStatus.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +   
        "Priority: " + rbtnPriority.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +
        "Reason for High Priority: " + txtboxReason.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "Project List /Code: " + ddlDeptList0.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +  
        "Project Tag: " + txtProjectTag.Text + "%0D%0A" +  
        "Project WSBE: " + txtWSBE.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "%0D%0A" +
        "Delivery Address: " + rbtnBuilding.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +
        "Company: " + rbtnCompany.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +
        "Category: " + rbtnCategory.SelectedValue + "%0D%0A" +
        "Suggested supplier: " + cboxSupplier.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Supplier 1: " + txtSupplier1.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "Supplier 2: " + txtSupplier2.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "%0D%0A" +
        "Required Supporting Documents" + "%0D%0A" +
        "Material Certificate: " + cboxMaterial.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "First Article Inspection: " + cboxFirstArticle.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Quality Inspection Report: " + cboxQA.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Surface Treatment Certificate: " + cboxSurface.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Heat Treatment Certificate: " + cboxHeat.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Technical Specification: " + cboxTech.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Dimensional Inspection Report: " + cboxDimension.Checked + "%0D%0A" +                                          
        "Environmental Test Report: " + cboxEnviro.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "MSDS: " + cboxMSDS.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Calibration Certificate: " + cboxCalib.Checked + "%0D%0A" +        
        "DDP: " + cboxDDP.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Acceptance Test Report: " + cboxATP.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Additional Documents: " + txtOtherDoc.Text + "%0D%0A" +
        "%0D%0A" +      
        "Parts / Items" + "%0D%0A" +
        "Additional Quote Attached: " + cboxAttach.Checked + "%0D%0A" +
        "Parts / Items List" + "%0D%0A";

    // Adding rows from the HTML table to the email body
    foreach (GridViewRow row in TblItems.Rows)
    {
        string itemNumber = ((Label)row.FindControl("ItemNr")).Text;
        string manuPartNr = ((Label)row.FindControl("ManuPartNr")).Text;
        string manufacturer = ((Label)row.FindControl("Manu")).Text;
        string incoPartNr = ((Label)row.FindControl("IncoPrtNr")).Text;
        string description = ((Label)row.FindControl("Descript")).Text;
        string quantity = ((Label)row.FindControl("quantity")).Text;
        string deliveryDate = ((Label)row.FindControl("DeliveryDate")).Text;

        body += itemNumber + " | " + manuPartNr + " | " + manufacturer + " | " + incoPartNr + " | " + description + " | " + quantity + " | " + deliveryDate + "%0D%0A";
    }

    Response.Redirect("mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body);
}


(You do realize, that this has nothing whatsoever to do with mailto:, right? Your question title is misleading, I'd say.)

And mailto: itself is not a particularly good idea to begin with; not least because the length limit at least in Chrome still appears to be around 2000 characters, which I'm guessing you might quite easily break here.
